Как в aiogram3 отправить боту сообщение, которое он обработает
У меня есть файл handlers.py
from aiogram import F, Router
from aiogram.filters import CommandStart, Command
from aiogram.types import Message, CallbackQuery
import app.keyboards as kb

router = Router()

@router.callback_query(F.data == 'addAcc')
async def send_GetAccounts(callback: CallbackQuery, state: FSMContext):
    await state.set_state(Auth.token)
    await callback.message.edit_text('Введите ссылку с токеном, полученный <a href=vkhost.github.io>ЗДЕСЬ</a>:',
                                     reply_markup=kb.GetAccount, parse_mode='html', disable_web_page_preview=True)

тут я хочу что бы в функции send_GetAccounts когда бот отправил сообщение Введите ссылку с токеном, полученный <a href=vkhost.github.io>ЗДЕСЬ</a>, дальше пользователь отправляет сообщение боту и дальше бот что-то с этим сообщением в другой функции делал.
Как это можно сделать ?
ДОПОЛНЕНО:
class Auth(StatesGroup):
    token = State()

@router.callback_query(StateFilter(None), F.data == 'addAcc')
async def send_GetAccounts(callback: CallbackQuery, state: FSMContext):
    await state.set_state(Auth.token)
    await callback.message.edit_text('Введите ссылку с токеном, полученный <a href=vkhost.github.io>ЗДЕСЬ</a>:',
                                     reply_markup=kb.GetAccount, parse_mode='html', disable_web_page_preview=True)


def check_token(token):
    access_token_match = re.search(r'access_token=([^&]+)', token).group(1)
    if access_token_match:
        access_token = access_token_match.group(1)
        vk_session = vk_api.VkApi(token=access_token)
        try:
            vk_session.auth(token_only=True)
            print('Авторизация прошла успешно')
            return True
        except vk_api.AuthError as err_msg:
            print(err_msg)
    return False



@router.message(Auth.token)
async def token_inputed(message: Message, state: FSMContext):
    if check_token(message.text):
        await message.answer("Успешно добавлен токен!")
        await state.clear()
    else:
        await message.answer("Некорректно введен токен!")```


Также, советую прочитать этот гайд:
https://mastergroosha.github.io/aiogram-3-guide/fsm/

Вот так ловить такие сообщения:
@router.message(Auth.token)
async def token_inputed(message: Message, state: FSMContext):
    if check_token(message.text): # типо проверяем полученные данные
        await message.answer("Успешно добавлен токен!")
        await state.clear()
    else:
        await message.answer("Некорректно введен токен!")
        # ничего не делаем

Но тогда лучше добавить в ваш send_GetAccounts проверку, что мы сейчас не ожидаем токен:
from aiogram.fsm.state import StatesGroup, State
from aiogram.filters import StateFilter
@router.callback_query(StateFilter(None), F.data == 'addAcc')
    # ...


Привет! Где то что вы мне скинули гайд на aiogram3 там есть все про эти состояния ??

А что за Auth.token?

Почему возникает ошиибка NameError: name 'StateFilter' is not defined

спасибо за уточнение, добавил недостающий импорт

Auth.token - это ваше текущее состояние. По вашему state.set_state(Auth.token), я подумал, что уже вы создали группу состояний. Видимо, я ошибся. Но в том материале там это предельно хорошо описано. Вкладка "Конечные автоматы"

Спасибо за ответы! Как думаете сколько нужно что бы на хорошем уровне делать телеграм ботов ?

Всегда пожалуйста! В принципе, нельзя сказать точно. Мой совет - придумывайте разные идеи, и пробуйте их реализовать. Может, они и не будут вам нужны, но у вас будет опыт!

можете еще написать почему бот не дает ответ? Я дополнил код где создал class Auth где у меня есть token далее когда пользователь в функции send_GetAccount отправляет ссылку токеном и в функции check_token извлекается токен и дальше бот должен написать Успешно добавлен токен! Но он ничего не пишет
